# Rails + Passenger CSS problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, permissions

I'm trying to deploy my first Rails app.

At first, I was getting the following error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (Permission denied)
```

I set the permissions of the stylesheets folder to 777 (just for now until I work out what's going wrong) and the application started to work.  However, it is not picking up any of the stylesheets (everything is displayed in plain text).  If I view the source code and click the CSS links, I just get a blank page.

Javascripts however, seem to be working just fine.

VHost Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxxx.xxx.com
DocumentRoot /home/myapp/public    
<Directory /home/myapp/public>
Allow from All
AllowOverride all             
Options -MultiViews           
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: could you post your vhost configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Anything interesting in your apache access logs?  (locally, mine are here: /var/log/apache2/access_log)

Add in `Order allow,deny` and `Allow from all`.  Many configs have their Directory value in quotes (though not required).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public
  <Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
  RailsBaseURI /
</VirtualHost>
```

though I have local passenger setup with just

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Options -MultiViews
```

And if it's your first rails app on OSX, may I recommend [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) and the [Passenger Preference Pane](http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working in the end by removing the cache option from my stylesheets.  It seems that the permissions weren't extending to the file that this created.